# Matlab clabel with figure-file

Tags: matlab, spacing

I´m facing a problem. I open a figure-file (.fig) in Matlab that is a 2D contourf-plot. I created the file with a software that is based on matlab but has a GUI: maptools. I added Isolines in the plot. Each Isoline is labeled by me (clabel in matlab). The problem now is that I can´t set the space between the labels of the isolines so that each isoline has a lot of labels say for example 5.

in Matlab it is pretty easy to fix that. just the following way:

```
[Cp hp] = contourf(x,y,levels);

clabel(Cp,hp,'LabelSpacing',150);
```

My Question now is whether it is possible to read in the figure-file in Matlab with `openfig(anyfigure.fig)` and change the space between the isoline labels. In other words, is there any isoline (or isoline label) handle for a figure file that is opened with `openfig()`

Thank you ;)

Comment: Can you please upload an example figure file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `contour`/`contourf` you are generating instances of a [`contour` object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html) that you can address directly. When loading in your figure, specify an output so you have the handle to your figure, which you can use with [findobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) to locate your `contour` object. This `contour` object is the second input to [`clabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clabel.html).

For example:

```
filepath = 'somepath';
myfig = openfig(filepath);
# Assume only one contour object in the figure
hp = findobj(myfig.Children, 'Type', 'contour');
clabel([], hp, 'LabelSpacing', 150);
```

Which generates the following for a [sample `contour` plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html#bty7w5z):

[image: yay]

Note that `clabel`, per the documentation, does not need the contour matrix input `C` if you have the handle to the `contour` object. The contour matrix is a property of the object so MATLAB can get it for itself.